# Looking for tutorials that are CURRENT & work with IntelliJ/UI Designer

Tags: java, android, intellij-13

I can't seem to find anything on Java/Android that's current (uses IntelliJ 13 etc). Everything seems to be either very old (2011-2012), and either the UI has changed, or they don't use the UI Designer etc

I'm not a total noob to programming, I have somewhat decent experience in C# & Windows Forms, and would love something that can throw me into Java for Android that's UP TO DATE.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have decent experience in C#/WinForms, you just need a good Android book, not IntelliJ/UI Designer tutorials… I recommend the excellent BigNerdRanch book. They make probably the best iOS books and the Android offers excellent patterns. With your experience, adapting to IntelliJ should be a breeze, in part because the IDE doesn't force you to do anything. In fact, if you're starting, just use Android Studio (is IntelliJ anyway). http://www.amazon.com/Android-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321804333/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1396316293&sr=8-1&keywords=Android+Big+Nerd+Ranch+Guide

Comment: the UP-TO-DATE part consists in always using Fragments, understanding the SDK pieces where you have to consider older devices (if that's your scope), making good use of different layouts for different resolutions, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still actually haming issues with things like UI Designer. Like with WinForms, I can place buttons etc ANYWHERE. But for some reason, they're locked into a grid it seems. Or when I change themes (Say to Holo Light W/ no Action Bar), it has no effect on the app UI when I run it on my Nexus 5.

Comment: Well, a piece of free advice, there's no such thing as Visual Studio Designer. (There is, but it doesn't work the same way). I recommend you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html with utmost care since it's the core of Android UI. For the most part, you will tweak your UI from the "XML" instead of the UI designer, which you can use to "see how it looks" or if "makes sense" but trust me, as intimidating as it sounds, it's actually not rocket science and you get used to it relatively fast.

Comment: I just realized the ook goes over UI design. Thanks Martin, you just saved my life lol

Comment: Also if you don't want to buy a book (yet), start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm just lazy. Easy = Good

Comment: The Android documentation is the best up-to-date source you will find, so don't forget about it. Bookmark it and use it frequently. I still do, even after a few years of Android development. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I should use this site more often.

Comment: I added everything as an answer so you can mark it, comments don't really help other people ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have decent experience in C#/WinForms, you just need a good Android book, not IntelliJ/UI Designer tutorials… I recommend the excellent [BigNerdRanch book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321804333). They make probably the best iOS books and the Android offers excellent patterns. With your experience, adapting to IntelliJ should be a breeze, in part because the IDE doesn't force you to do anything. In fact, if you're starting, just use Android Studio (is IntelliJ anyway).

The UP-TO-DATE part consists in always using Fragments, understanding the SDK pieces where you have to consider older devices (if that's your scope), making good use of different layouts for different resolutions, etc.

There's no such thing as Visual Studio Designer. (There is, but it doesn't work the same way). I recommend you read [the official android documentation about UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) with utmost care since it's the core of Android UI. For the most part, you will tweak your UI from the "XML" instead of the UI designer, which you can use to "see how it looks" or if "makes sense" but trust me, as intimidating as it sounds, it's actually not rocket science and you get used to it relatively fast.

Comment: +1 for Big Nerd Ranch, great iOS and Android books.